# Finding the power of x using recursion the fast way

Tags: python, recursion

Fast recursive power. Write a more ecient recursive function recPowerSlow(x,n), which given a
number x and an integer n, returns x^n. Aim for (log n) arithmetic operations. Try your function
on the test cases in Part (a).
Below is the idea illustrated via an example:
The naive method to compute x9 is:

```
x9 = x8x
x8 = x7x
x7 = x6x
x6 = x5x
x5 = x4x
x4 = x3x
x3 = x2x
x2 = xx
A much more ecient method is:
x^9 = x^8 x
x^8 = (x^4)2
x^4 = (x^2)2
x^2 = (x)^2
```

First assume n  1. Write a recursive definition to calculate x^n inspired by the above example.
Once you figure out the recurrence, the recursive function follows easily. Then take care of the cases
n < 0 and n = 0.

Here  is my code:

```
def recPowerSlow1(x,n):
    if n==0
    return 1
    elif n%2==0:
    return x*recPowerSlow1(x,n-1)
    else:
    return n*n*recPowerSlow1(x,n//2)
    print(recPowerSlow1(4,3))
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question and post your error. Also, please indent your code.

Comment: It feels like you just dumped your homework on stackoverflow. That is not how stackoverflow works. Please try to come up with your solution, point out precisely where you have a problem.